# Strange behavior of margin

Tags: css, margin

This sounds a stupid question but it really perplexes me. Fiddle is here:http://jsfiddle.net/rLL3p7k5/1/

```
<div id='a'></div>
<div id='b'>
    <div id="c"></div>text in box-b</div>
<div id="d">text in box-d</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width:400px;
    height:100px
}
#a {
    background:red
}
#b {
    background:blue;
}
#c {
    background:yellow;
    width:50%;
    height:50px;
    margin:20px auto 100px auto
}
#d {
    background:green;
    color:white
}
```

box-c's margin-top is making a gap between box-a and box-b, I'd thought that margin-bottom would do the same thing and make a gap between box-b and box-d, but actually no matter what the margin-bottom value is, box-d will always stick to box-b. So what is behind this behavior discrepancy between margin-top and margin-bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `margin-bottom:20px` to box-b if you want, or you can achieve the same by adding `margin-top:20px` to box-d:

```css
div{width:400px;height:100px}
#a{background:red}
#b{background:blue;margin-bottom:20px}
#c{background:yellow;width:50%;height:50px;margin:20px auto 100px auto}
#d{background:green;color:white}
```

```html
<div id='a'></div>
<div id='b'><div id="c"></div>text in box-b</div>
<div id="d">text in box-d</div>
```

want to keep the gap:

Comment: My question was why margin-top and margin-bottom behave differently ?